# ASP.NET core label taghelper. How to append custom text

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

When we write

```
<label asp-for="Email"></label>
```

it generates the following HTML:

```
<label for="Email">Email Address</label>
```

It works fine. The question is whether it's possible to extend tag helper to support custom text to be added? For example, if I write

```
<label asp-for="Email" asp-postfix=":"></label>
```

it generates the following HTML:

```
<label for="Email">Email Address:</label>
```

Please see that colon is added now to the label text. And colon could be replaced with any other text.

Comment: Just add <label>:</label>  after <label asp-for="Email"></label>

Answer (score 7):

If you're planning on extending the current aspnet tag helper, you can't. You will need to create your own tag helper. Both the aspnet and your one will run.

```
[HtmlTargetElement("label", Attributes = _textAttributeName)]
public class PostfixTagHelper : TagHelper
{
    private const string _textAttributeName = "postfix-text";

    [HtmlAttributeName(_textAttributeName)]
    public string Text { get; set; }

    public override void Process(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
    {
        base.Process(context, output);

        output.Content.Append(Text);
    }

    public override int Order
    {
        get
        {
            return 100; // Needs to run after aspnet
        }
    }
}
```

To use it:

```
<label asp-for="Email" postfix-text=":"></label>
```

Answer (score 1):

in tag helper if you have static content in source and want to append text then refer below link. https://github.com/aspnet/Razor/issues/341. for reference added same example over here.

Source File

```
<my-tag-helper>
    Content in source
</my-tag-helper>
```

Tag helper file.

```
public void Process(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
{
    var nl = Environment.NewLine;
    var br = "<br />" + nl;
    output.PreElement.Append("This will appear before source element" + br);
    output.PreContent.Append(nl + "This will appear before source content" + br);
    output.PostContent.Append(br + "This will appear after source content" + nl);
    output.PostElement.Append(br + "This will appear after source element");
}
```

Output.

```
This will appear before source element<br />
<my-tag-helper>
This will appear before source content<br />
    Content in source<br />
This will appear after source content
</my-tag-helper><br />
This will appear after source element
```

Answer (score -1):

This works nicely:

```
<form method="post" class="container mt-3 backgroundwhite w-100">
   <div class="form-group row">
      <label class="col-4 text-right pr-1" style="" asp-for="ServiceToBeAdded.Name"></label><span>: &nbsp;</span>
      <input class="form-control col-6" asp-for="ServiceToBeAdded.Name" type="text" />
  </div>
  <div class="form-group row">
    <label class="col-4 text-right pr-1" asp-for="ServiceToBeAdded.Price"></label><span>: &nbsp;</span>
    <input class="form-control col-6" asp-for="ServiceToBeAdded.Price" type="text" />
  </div>

</form>
```